# Is there any way I can "convert" a ejs file to jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, ejs

I have a ejs file that I would like to include in my jade-based app but I don't know how.

Comment: I would suggest converting it manually, there are no converters around that do that for you as far as I could tell.

Comment: If you remove all the <% %> delimiters (and JavaScript in between) you'll be left with just your HTML. That HTML can be converted using an online tool (Google searched: http://html2jade.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late here, but for those who searched this like I did:

There is a tool called html to jade: http://html2jade.org

It does not convert the embedded javascript part to pug/jade but it takes care of the html part and you can inject the js yourself.